# Move or shift array element to last postion by condition + ruby array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I need to shift an element to last position by condition.
For ex. 
`[1,2,3]` and to put `1` in last in array, without executing unnecessary loops.

`o/p [2,3,1]` for the above condition array will be dynamic and put particular element on last by condition.

I tried like this:

```
sd = [1,2,3]
sd.map{|d| sd.last(d) if d ==1 }
```

but the output is `[[3], nil, nil]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have [`Array#rotate`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-rotate) method :-

```
[3] pry(main)> a = [1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
[4] pry(main)> a.rotate(1)
=> [2, 3, 1]
[5] pry(main)> a.rotate(2)
=> [3, 1, 2]
```

In your case, you should pass *1* as argument to the method `#rotate`. But `1` is default argument to the `#rotate` method, so you can *omit* it too. [*bang* version of `#rotate`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-rotate-21) also exist.